# Different methods of concatenation return different output

Tags: php, concatenation

I am definitely not a PHP expert, but I would figure that the following snippets output the same HTML. But they don't.

```
echo '<a href="';
the_permalink();
echo '" title="';
the_title();
echo '"><i class="genericon-standard"></i></a>';
```

Returns (as it should):

```
<a href="http://my-site.com/?p=1" title="Hallo wereld!"><i class="genericon-standard"></i></a>
```

But the much shorter code

```
echo '<a href="' . the_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title() . '"><i class="genericon-standard"></i></a>';
```

Returns

```
http://my-site.com/?p=1Hallo wereld!<a href="" title=""><i class="genericon-standard"></i></a>
```

Which is *not* what I want, obviously. Where do I go wrong in the second code (the shorter)?

Comment: I'd suggest that functions like `the_permalink()` and `the_title()` __echo__ a value rather than __return__ a value

Comment: can you post the `the_permalink()` code too

Comment: i think `the_permalink()` is echoing the output instead of returning the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_permalink()` echos the permalink, `get_permalink()` returns the permalink.

So the second way should be like below:

```
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '"><i class="genericon-standard"></i></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Wordpress, so you must use get_permalink() and get_the_title() instead of the_permalink because this function will echo the result and break your string.

Alternatively you can store the permalink in a variable and then concatenate to your string:

```
$permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
```

Here is the documentation:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress get_permalink() and get_the_title() functions shows the values